# In-App Purchase Products for IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

How to add multiple product in managed in-app purchase with same price tier in IOS IN 0.99$?
For eg: 1000 products.

Comment: will you please explain your problem in detail? we are getting confuse with these two short lines. add a detailed description here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i dont think that you can make a single product purchase 1000 times, you must define 1000 product in itune connect & configure them as well.

here is reference link [for In-App Purchase Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Products.html)

A product is something you want to sell in your app’s store. You create and configure products in iTunes Connect, and your app interacts with products using the SKProduct and SKProductsRequest classes.

**Creating Products in iTunes Connect**

Before you start coding, you need to configure products in iTunes Connect for your app to interact with. As you develop your app, you can add and remove products and refine or reconfigure your existing products.

Every product is associated with a specific app. Products created for use by one app are not available in other apps. Companion apps on a different platform are different apps—the products of the Mac app are not available in the iOS app and vice versa.

Products are reviewed when you submit your app as part of the app review process. Before users can buy a product, it must be approved by the reviewer and you must mark it as “cleared for sale” in iTunes Connect.

For step-be-step information about working with products in iTunes Connect,[In-App Purchase Configuration Guide for iTunes Connect](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013727)

Comment: I think he is talking about selling something like 1000 coins in the application for $0.99

Here, the IAP must be configured to `consumable`, and the logic to sell the item is completely under the control of the developer. You can present the item for sale however you like, you then implement the necessary code available from Apple. 

These include the receipt and/or previous purchase, such as if your app was previously published in iOS6 and users previously made the purchase, else, you would implement the new receipt only. Check out the WWDC sections for more.